# SQLite запрос в 2 разные таблицы и объединение в 3-й

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

У меня есть 3 таблица:

- Timetable
- Students
- Groups

В **Timetable** у меня хранятся записи расписания, ниже скрин.

[image: Структура таблицы timetable]

В **Client_id**  я храню id объекта из таблицы **Students** или **Groups** (т.е. в расписании может быть указана или группа или 1 человек)

**Type** - хранит одно из значений **s** или **g** - что соответствует объекту из таблицы **S**tudents или **G**roups.

Мне нужен запрос, чтобы получить следующую таблицу:

[image: Пример необходимой таблицы]

В идеале конечно запрос где есть - `... WHERE Day = ?`

Если есть идеи другой реализации БД - приму как за ответ.

Сокращенная структура таблиц **Students** и **Groups**:

[image: Сокращенная структура 2 таблиц]

Данные в таблицах

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/04a47

[image: Данные таблицы Students]
[image: Данные таблицы Groups]

[image: Данные таблицы Timetable]

Comment: Ответ несложный, но чтоб оформить его можно было относительно быстро, нужно улучшить вопрос. Почитайте, как задать хороший вопрос по sql https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1035/218971

Comment: @RomanKonoval скорректировал вопрос

Comment: Надо было не только скорректировать вопрос, но и прочитать тему по ссылке. Тогда не пришло бы в голову вместо пригодного к копированию текста выкладывать скриншоты... Особе внимание обратите на пункты 2.3 и 3.

Comment: @Akina http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/04a47

Comment: *Мне нужен запрос, чтобы получить следующую таблицу* Пожалуйста, опишите подробно логику получения этого результата. Из приложенного скриншота в принципе не понять, что собственно происходит. И покажите ПОЛНОСТЬЮ требуемый ответ, все поля и все значения. Форматированным в таблицу текстом. PS. Перенёс данные в https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c5409e204c658568552f88af78011bb8 - оно стабильнее работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо сделать запрос в каждую таблицу и после объединить их.

```
SELECT tt.id, tt.time, tt.day, gr.name FROM Timetable as tt INNER JOIN Groups as gr On gr.id = tt.client_id WHERE tt.Type = 'g'
UNION 
SELECT tt.id, tt.time, tt.day, st.name || ' ' || st.surname as name FROM Timetable as tt INNER JOIN students as st On st.id = tt.client_id WHERE tt.Type = 's'
```